Cards with specific order
We have a deck of 99 cards each of which has a distinct real number written on it, and the sum of the all numbers is irrational. A specific order of the cards is said to be good if sum of the k top cards is alo irrational for any k. What is the minimum number of good orders? For example if all the numbers, except one of them is rational, we have a good order: place the card with irrational number at top. Do there exist 99 numbers whose sum is irrational, with no good order? That is, for any rearrangement of the cards, there is some m, for which the sum of top m cards is irrstional. It seems for any choice of such numbers, there is at least one good order but do not know how to prove this in the general case. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point might be to solve the problem for smaller decks of cards.

You can show this by induction on the deck size - do you see why such a deck with 99 cards must necessarily have some subcollection of 98 cards that still has an irrational sum? (Hint: Can the sum of all of these 98 smaller sums be rational?)

A single card with irrational value is enough to make the sum irrational. And if all cards are irrational, then their sum will be irrational too. So number of irrational cards in the deck=$l$ will be $1≤l≤99$

Also the topmost card doesn't have to be on top when there is a single irrational card. Say it's the 94th card from top. So sum of 94 cards from top will be irrational, implying it's a good order

@Gwen for all $k$... not just for a particular $k$.  Read the post again.  If you have only one irrational card and it occurred in position $94$, then it would not be a good order since for $k=1,2,3,4,\dots,93$ you would have the sum of the first $k$ happened to be rational (and not irrational).

So it's a good order when $k=1,2,...93$ will all be irrational? @JMoravitz

@Gwen it is only a "good" order when all of the sums will be irrational... all of them including $k=1$ and $k=2$ and $k=3$ etc... on up to $k=99$.  It is a bad order if at least one of the sums $k=1$ or $k=2$ etc... are rational.

@TimSeifert If sum of any subcollection of size 98 is rational, then sum of all numbers is rational (we consider the intersection of such sucollections and union of these intersections form the set of all 99 numbers)as well and this is a contradiction.

"And if all cards are irrational, then their sum will be irrational too" . This is in general false.

@Fermat Note that in your example, there are multiple good orders as just the first card is forced. It is not hard to see that there must be several good orders as soon as there are at least 3 cards: If $(a,b,c)$ is a unique good order, then $ a+c$ and $b+c$ are both rational. But then $(b,a,c)$ also works. Thus, even the initial segment of length 3 of such a good order is never unique.

By doing some case splitting, we can even see that we are always able to swap two cards in any segment of length three in a good order and again obtain a good order. By splitting 99 into 33 runs of three cards each, this shows that there are at least $2^{33}$ good orders. And this is probably still a very low bound.

@TimSeifert Yes, you are right. In the given example, one can easily permute rational numbers and this does not affect the good-ness of that order. This produces (n-1)! good orders. Or even permute any subset of them.

Just to aggregate my comments into an answer: For any deck size $n$, there is a good order. In fact, there are at least $2^{\lfloor\frac{n}{3} \rfloor}$ such orders.
Let me make one observation before going into the proof. The numbers on the cards as well as their sum only matter up to addition of rational numbers, i.e. we are really working in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ here. The proof then works just as well for cards labeled with entries from any torsion-free abelian group $A$. I will use this language from now on. The demand for a good order $a_1,...,a_n$ then translates to the property that each partial sum $a_1+...+a_k$ must be nonzero in $A$. (At least I find it cleaner to think and write about sums being (non)zero rather than being (ir)rational.)
The proof of existence then goes like this: Clearly, a deck with one card and overall nonzero sum has a (unique) good order. Now, suppose that claim is true for decks of size $n$ and suppose we have a deck of size $n+1$ with cards $a_1,...,a_{n+1}$ and sum $s\neq 0$. Consider all the $n+1$ decks obtained by removing a single card $a_i$ and denote their sum as $s_i$. Then clearly $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}s_i =ns\neq 0,$$
as $A$ is torsion-free. Hence, there must be at least one nonzero summand $s_i$, that is, one subdeck of size $n$ with a nonzero sum. By induction, this has a good order, which can be extended to a good order of the full deck by appending it with the omitted $a_i$.
It remains to see that there are at least $2^{\lfloor\frac{n}{3} \rfloor}$ such orders. To that end, we will show that for a run of three cards $a_{i-1},a_i,a_{i+1}$ in any given good order, we may swap two of these entries around and still obtain a good order. By splitting the deck into segments of length $3$ (and possibly some remainder), our claim then immediately follows. So, suppose that we have some good order $a_1,...,a_n$ and we are interested in the run from $a_{i-1}$ to $a_{i+1}$. For ease of notation label these as $a,b,c$ and denote the sum of the entries before as $s$. Clearly, no permutation of these entries can affect the partial sums strictly before or after this segment, so that the only entries up for discussion are $s+a$ and $s+a+b$.
Suppose for a contradiction that $s+a$ and $s+a+b$ are nonzero, but no swapping of two entries achieves that effect. Since we cannot swap $a$ with $b$, we conclude that $s+b=0$ (as the second sum is unaltered), so that $b=-s$. Also, since we cannot swap $b$ with $c$, we must have $s+a+c=0$, so that $c=-s-a$. Finally, since we cannot swap $a$ and $c$, one of the numbers
$s+c=-a$ or $s+b+c=-s-a$ must be zero. But the second one cannot be (since $s+a$ is already a partial sum), so that $a=0$ necessarily. But this in turn implies that $s+a+b=0$, which is also a contradiction. Hence, some swap must have lead to a good order, which shows the claim. (It is not too difficult to find examples that only admit a single swap, so that this result cannot be directly improved.)
I have not undertaken a similar analysis for longer segments, but I would strongly suspect that (say) a sequence of length 6 is guaranteed to have many more reorderings than the $4$ given by the bound.
Finally, note that the assumption of $A$ being torsion-free is essential for the existence of good orders: If $A$ has an element $a$ of order $n$, we can just look at the $n+1$ card deck with each card labeled by $a$. This clearly has no good order, since the penultimate sum must evaluate to $0$. But an adaptation of the argument works for any abelian group $A$ and deck of size $n$, as long as $A$ has no (nonzero) elements of order less than $n$ (and this is clearly sharp).

There are always at least one good order. First we're going to prove this lemma:
LEMMA: For $n$ given numbers, $n \geq 2$, if their sum is irrational, then there exists at least one way to choose $n-1$ numbers from them such that their sum is irrational.
EDIT: shorter proof thanks to DS
Proof: Let $a_1,a_2,..,a_n$ be the real numbers. Then
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i\neq k}^{n}a_k = (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i
\end{align}
$$
Since the RHS is irrational, at least one of the sums $\sum_{i\neq k}^{n}a_k$ is irrational.
Thus, there is at least one way to choose $n-1$ number such that their sum is irrational from the given $n$ numbers.
Given the lemma, we can choose the last number such that the other $n-1$ numbers have an irrational sum. But we can repeat applying this lemma, and choose the next number, and so on. Therefore, we achieve the desired order.
P/s: I have tried to extend the proof to at least $(n-1)!$ ways but was unsuccessful.

@DS I see, that's actually better
